# Can I use a derailleur hanger in my old frame?

Tags: derailleur, drivetrain

I'm trying to adapt an old '83 Fuji Del Rey frame with the parts of my broken '86 Fuji Espree and I'm having problems adapting the Derailleur.

The Del Rey frame doesn't come with the little hook where the derailleur was in the other frame and I'm wondering if I can adapt a derailleur hanger to it.
I've done research but there are a lot of different models and I don't know how to evaluate.

Is there a generic one that can be attached directly to where the wheel goes?

Thanks in advance!

This is a detail photo of the Espree:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrfAJ.jpg

And this is a detail of the Del Rey with my wheel on it. (I realized it's not very clear, I'll upload new pics as I get home)

http://cl.ly/IaY5/IMG_2724.JPG

Answer (score 2):

There are replacement hangers to adapt a modern deraileur to horizontal drops. I have never used one and can't say how well they work. BikeParts.com lists this Shimano compatable piece ID#: BPC109497 that  may do the trick. Talk to someone at the LBS (local bike shop) first,if you get it locally you will be able to try it for fit before buy it.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon has shimano derailleur adapters which should probably do the job.

[http://www.amazon.com/Shimano-Rear-derailleur-mount-adapter/dp/B003UW4AXS/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1344370705&sr=8-1&keywords=shimano+sis+rear+derailleur+adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003UW4AXS)